# Vector Terminology

Tags: vectors, terminology

In greek, we learn that a vector in 3D space has three basic characteristics, namely,

- μήκος --> magnitude (length)
- διεύθυνση --> a line the vector is on
- φορά --> the way the vector faces on that line

So, a vector is a line segment having **direction**. (Wikipedia)

It can be seen that the only thing that distinguishes a vector from a line segment is *the way the vector faces on the line that it is on*.

In greek referring to both last two characteristics, we say 'κατεύθυνση' which translates to **direction**. It seems though, all three words translate to **direction**, so, I was wondering what to call *the line the vector is on* and *the way the vector faces on that line* if needed to separate them.

To be clear, *the way the vector faces* given a line can be one of two things. If we arbitrarily pick a plus and minus side of the line, the vector faces the negative side when to draw it we start at a point on the line and draw a line segment of some length towards the negative side.

Comment: I would say a vector is _parallel_ to a line, not that it is _on_ the line. Thinking that a vector has a particular location leads to confusion later when you need to understand that the vector from $(2,0)$ to $(3,2)$ and the vector from $(0,0)$ to $(1,2)$ are the _same vector._

Comment: Thank you for your comment! When mentioning the line the vector is *on* I was not thinking about location. I was thinking about orientation. I would point it out in my answer and question.

Comment: "Parallel to" conveys the idea of orientation without implying anything about location. That's why I like those particular words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector in 3D space can be fully described by three characteristics.

**Magnitude** which comes from ordering vectors according to size.

**Orientation** which comes from rotating the axes of a reference frame.

**Sense** which comes from associating the vector with a set of half lines.

**Orientation** and **sense** fully describe **direction**.

We actually care for the **orientation** of *the line the vector is on* and determining its **sense** (the set of all half lines who have the same orientation and by pairs belong to the same part of the half plane they define) is equivalent to *the way the vector faces on that line*.